# Configure the geoserver gdal plugin on Debian buster running open Jre11

Tags: geoserver, gdal

I am trying to setup the gdal plugin in a geoserver docker container for geoserver 2.16 series. I have installed libgdal java and gdal but I get the following error 
No gdaljni in java library path.
  I have set the LD_Library path and downloaded the image io extensions and setup gdal_data env variables.
Most of the articles I have seen reference old links which are not useful.

Comment: i have the same problem ! Did you find a solution with this issue ?

Comment: Partially, I disabled the imageio ext from the LD path environment and it works with the gdal formats.  But it will be missing MrSid and ECW

Comment: I also need ECW for my project. Actually i follow this post :  https://gist.github.com/1papaya/568c4580b1909071696c1cb119101823   my gdalinfo : gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
  ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.4)
  JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.4) seemes to be OK but i can't link with geoserver...

Comment: Finally I work around removing openJDK and all gdal reference. I reinstall openJDK and  gdal-bin libgdal-java packages. Anyway ECW file type are not yet handled.